# Вопрос по Solidity Ethereum. DeFi

Tags: token, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smart-contract

Начал разбираться в blockchain, учить solidity для smart contract - ов на ethereum.
Интересуюсь DeFi, никак не пойму...
К примеру развернул контракт с токеном,
запустил проект DeFi с какими то минимальными услугами, для начало!
Планирую по этапно добавлять разные услуги, контракты, сервисы DeFi, это реально?
Или весь проект нужно сначала написать, а потом запускать?
"Надеюсь понятно спросил" Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать базовый смарт-контракт, который будет выполнять роль прокси к вновь добавляемым услугам. То есть делаете в смарте метод AssignService(service_name, address), который кладет во внутреннюю табличку связку service_name -> adress, а затем при вызове метода CallService(service_name, ...) перенаправляет вызов на address. Но тут надо изначально продумать всю систему параметров, которые будут передаваться следом или какой-то механизм задания "свободного" списка параметров.